# Get Updated and created date values in graph ql query using JSS react next js app

Tags: jss, graphql

I am trying to fetch updated date of an item via graphql query using jss Sitecore app.
I have done a bit of research and found out that I need to extend graphql schema in order to get updated date.

Can some one please guide me a way to get updated date

I found this query while searching

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/Content/Home", language: "en") {
    name
    versions {
      path
      field(name: "__updated"){
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the issue is, I am not getting versions. I am getting error message

```
"message": "Cannot query field \"versions\" on type \"Item\". Did you mean \"version\"?",
```

Comment: I tried it and it's working well for me for `Sitecore 9.3` version. Can you please confirm what version you are using?

Comment: @SumitBhatia i am using 10.2

Comment: It is not supported.